# How to fix "uncommitted xmin from before xid cutoff needs to be frozen, automatic vacuum of table "db.pg_catalog.pg_largeobject"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, autovacuum

PostgreSQL Database error log generate this error all day and still continue error to next day

```
[23523] ERROR:  uncommitted xmin 53354897 from before xid cutoff 210760077 needs to be frozen
[23523] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "xxxx.pg_catalog.pg_largeobject"
[23523] ERROR:  uncommitted xmin 53354897 from before xid cutoff 210760077 needs to be frozen
[23523] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "xxxx.pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata"
```

The error are involve system catalogs (`pg_catalog.pg_largeobject`, `pg_catalog.pg_largeobject_metadata`).

I need help about how to fix it or what will be affected if I disable autovacuum on these 2 tables.

Note:

- DB : PostgreSQL version 11.6
- OS : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are experiencing data corruption, and if you don't take action, you are headed for disaster: if autovacuum keeps failing (as it will), you will eventually get close enough to transaction ID wraparound that your database will stop accepting transactions.

Create a new database cluster, dump the corrupted cluster with `pg_dumpall`, restore it into the new cluster and remove the old one.

You are running an old minor release (current is 11.10), so you are missing about a year of bug fixes.  The cause could be a software bug or (more often) a hardware problem.

Comment: Dear Laurenz, Thank you for the suggestion. I tried by pg_basebackup and restore to new database environment (UAT) but the errors still generate with the same xmin number even if no connection in the new env. So how to kill the xmin of that large object?

Comment: `pg_basebackup` will not work. There is a reason why I told you to use `pg_dumpall`.

Answer (score 0):

As Laurenz told you, is data corruption, but you don't have to dumpall and restore.

If your row registry is not so important, you can delete it by the xmin number 53354897.

To get more safety, you can dump before and delete after that, achieving no downtime.

In my case, that error happened in a log table and I could delete it without get any data injury.

Observation: If you got corruption on your data, you have to check your hardware and data integrity as well, even if you delete the problematic row.